# Can pointer to 2D array item be NULL?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, null

A static analysis program (LDRA), has an issue with the following statement:

```
const float    range_min = p_results_phase->range_min;
```

The analyzer says the pointer `p_results_phase` needs to be tested for NULL.

Here's the definition:

```
Cal_Ver_Results_t const * const     p_results_phase = &results[test_num][CAL_VER_PHASE];
```

The array `results` is defined in the function declaration:

```
void DrawVACalibrationVerificationResultsScreen(Cal_Ver_Results_t results[][CAL_VER_SI_COUNT], unsigned int test_num)
```

My understanding is that the pointer `p_results_phase` cannot be NULL because the pointer is assigned to point to a location within the array `results`.

### Edit 1: actual code (in order):

```
Cal_Ver_Results_t const * const     p_results_phase = &results[test_num][CAL_VER_PHASE];
const float                         range_min = p_results_phase->range_min;
const float                         range_max = p_results_phase->range_max;
```

[image: Screen snapshot as additioinal proof of no intervening code between definition and usage.]

### Questions:

1. Will the pointer `p_results_phase` be assigned to NULL if the `test_num` variable is out of bounds?
2. Will the pointer `p_results_phase` be assigned to NULL if the `CAL_VER_PHASE` is out of bounds?

Definition of `Cal_Ver_Results_t`:

```
typedef struct Cal_Ver_Results_s {
    float result1;
    float result2;
    float range_min;
    float range_max;
    _Bool pass;
}Cal_Ver_Results_t;
```

Comment: I believe you're right, this seems to be a bug in the static analysis.

Comment: Taking the address of an array element will never yield a NULL pointer. But if the array pointer itself is NULL, or the element is out of bounds, then taking the address would be undefined behavior

Comment: You might have omitted some other portions of the code that might make the analyzer think that the pointer can become NULL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How can the pointer be NULL?  It's assigned to point to a slot in the array without any intervening code.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was referring to the `results` parameter of `DrawVACalibrationVerificationResultsScreen()`, the caller might pass in a NULL array pointer

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Re “The array `results` is defined in the function declaration: `void DrawVACalibrationVerificationResultsScreen(Cal_Ver_Results_t results[][CAL_VER_SI_COUNT], unsigned int test_num)`”: That is not a definition of an array. It is a nominally declaration of a parameter to be an array but that is automatically adjusted to declare the parameter as a pointer. You can assert that the pointer points to an array with at least 1 element elements by changing it to `Cal_Ver_Results_t results[static 1][CAL_VER_SI_COUNT]`, but I do not know whether that will pacify your static analyzer.

Comment: Another option would be to assert it has at least `test_num+1` elements, which would be done with `Cal_Ver_Results_t results[static test_num+1][CAL_VER_SI_COUNT]`, but unfortunately `test_num` is declared after `results`. If you can swap the parameter order, you might try that.

Comment: LDRA is infamous for its many false positives. Is this listed as a MISRA violation or a violation reported by another module (data anomaly check etc)? Also note that LDRA is somewhat smarter/less dumb during analysis when working on a whole project than a single .c file.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer value is computed from the address of the array received as a function argument.  If `results` was defined as a local or global array, and assuming the element is inside the array boundaries, the pointer cannot be null, but in spite of the array syntax in the function argument definition, `results` is passed as a pointer, so the function could receive a null pointer as an argument.  In this case, computing `p_results_phase` as `&results[test_num][CAL_VER_PHASE]` produces an invalid pointer, dereferencing it has undefined behavior.

The computed pointer may be null, but this would be a coincidence: for example if both `test_num` and `CAL_VER_PHASE` are `0` and `results` is a null pointer.  Comparing `p_results_phase` to `NULL` is of limited value, but checking that `result` is not a null pointer is a more general sanity check.

As for your other questions:

> Will the pointer `p_results_phase` be assigned to `NULL` if the `test_num` variable is out of bounds?

Quite unlikely, but in this case `p_results_phase` will be an invalid pointer, which must not be dereferenced.

> Will the pointer `p_results_phase` be assigned to `NULL` if the `CAL_VER_PHASE` is out of bounds?

Same as above, `p_results_phase` will be an invalid pointer. Dereferencing it would have undefined behavior. The pointer may point to another entry in the array or outside the array, anything can happen when you dereference an invalid pointer.

As you confirm that `test_num` is an index into the array, you might want to check that it is in the proper bounds, but the array size is not provided so you probably have to trust the caller.

You can check that `results` is not a null pointer very simply with

```
    if (!results) {
        /* signal some error */
        return;
    }
```

C99 introduced a syntax to specify the minimum number of elements for a function argument declared with the array syntax. For example the function could be declared and defined as:

```
void DrawVACalibrationVerificationResultsScreen(
    Cal_Ver_Results_t results[static 10][CAL_VER_SI_COUNT],
    unsigned int test_num)
{
    ...
}
```

This tells the compiler that `results` points to an array of at least `10` arrays of `CAL_VER_SI_COUNT` `Cal_Ver_Results_t` objects.

With this prototype, it should not allow passing a null pointer explicitly and might produce a warning if it cannot tell if a function argument is indeed an array of the expected minimum length.

Similarly, the static code analyzer should be able to assume that `results` cannot be a null pointer and thus `p_results_phase` neither, provided the index values used are within the 2D array boundaries.

This feature has not gained wide acceptance, especially among developers targeting embedded systems, possibly due to poor compiler support. IMHO, the syntax is cumbersome and unintuitive: i would not advocate rewriting `strlen`'s prototype as `size_t strlen(const char s[static 1])` to underscore the need for the pointer to be non null, much less those of `strcpy()` and friends for which it would address only one of the constraints on these functions' arguments.

Comment: The `test_num` is an index and not capacity.

Comment: Please provide an example of testing the 2d array for NULL.  I've never tested an array parameter for NULL, only pointers. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: There are no array parameters. Any parameter declared as an array is automatically adjusted to be a pointer, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 7.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Let me test my understanding.  A function parameter declared as an array will allow the compiler better diagnostics, but inside the function, the array is represented as a pointer.  Interesting, I can use both array notation and pointer notation and still be correct?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, the declarations `void f(int x[42]);` and `void f(int *x);` mean *exactly* the same thing. The same in function definitions.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: when you pass an array to a function, the function receives a pointer to the first element.  The function argument can be written with the array syntax, but the leftmost size is meaningless (in your case it is omitted) and the function definition is exactly equivalent to its alternative using the potentially less readable pointer syntax: `void DrawVACalibrationVerificationResultsScreen(Cal_Ver_Results_t (*results)[CAL_VER_SI_COUNT], unsigned int test_num)`  Note the extra `()` around `*result`: they are very important!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Re “A function parameter”: This should be phrased as “a parameter declared as an array” because C also has function parameters that are parameters that are declared as functions. Those are also adjusted to be pointers (to functions). Re “I can use both array notation and pointer notation and still be correct?”: If you mean `a[i]` and `a+i`: The subscript operator operates on pointers, not arrays. If an array is used for `a` in `a[i]`, it is automatically converted to a pointer, and then the subscript operation is performed. The same conversion occurs in for an array in `a+i`.

Comment: Since it seems likely that the OP is using MISRA C, please note that MISRA bans the use of `static` inside function array parameters. The rationale is the incredibly shaky compiler support for this feature. Mainstream compilers didn't really support it until just a few years ago and support for it remains shaky and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**, if you're unlucky.

Particularly, you need to ensure:

1. That the parameter `results` is not `NULL`. Although it is syntactically declared like an array, in reality it behaves pretty much like ordinary pointer.
2. That `test_num` is, as you say, within bounds. Having it out of bounds might not lead to `p_result_phase` being `NULL`, that would be an unlucky coincidence, but it would point to nowhere and lead to UB.
3. `CAL_VER_PHASE` should also have a valid value, but it is customary that uppercase identifiers are constants, so its value should be OK (please do check).

Comment: Although function parameter `results` is declared like an array, that actually declares it *as* a pointer.  No need to equivocate with "pretty much", and I've no idea what other kind of pointer you may have in mind than an "ordinary" one.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that the pointer `p_results_phase` cannot be NULL because the pointer is assigned to point to a location within the array `results`.

Well yes, but more generally, `p_results_phase` is initialized with the result of an expression in the unary `&` operator.  As long as the operand is a valid lvalue, the `&` operation computes its address, which is required to compare unequal to every null pointer.  And if the operand is not a valid lvalue then it's not so much a question of the operation possibly yielding a null pointer, but rather of the operation having undefined behavior.  Adding a null check would not in any way address that.

In particular,

> 1. Will the pointer `p_results_phase` be assigned to NULL if the `test_num` variable is out of bounds?
> 2. Will the pointer `p_results_phase` be assigned to NULL if the `CAL_VER_PHASE` is out of bounds?

The C language specification does not answer either of these questions.  Attempting to reference an array element via an out-of-bounds index produces undefined behavior.  In practice, that UB is unlikely to manifest as the address being computed as a null pointer, but it could.  That's largely irrelevant, however, because undefined behavior is not localized.  If there is an out-of-bounds access then that itself is the issue, not that the resulting UB allows for the program to behave as if the computed pointer value was null.

> The analyzer says the pointer `p_results_phase` needs to be tested for NULL.

The analyzer is wrong.  Nevertheless, if you are required to appease it then you may need to add the useless null check.  More likely than not, your compiler is smarter than the analyzer and will remove the extra check when you compile with optimization enabled.

Alternatively, there may be a way (a specially-constructed comment, for example) to instruct the analyzer to ignore this perceived issue.  If so, that might be worth consideration, especially if your compiler happens to warn about the null check being extraneous, which is conceivable.

Answer (score 0):

Static analysis tools are often about applying/enforcing a coding standard, rather than detecting bugs directly.  The purpose of coding standards is to reduce bugs in maintenance and reuse.

In this case testing for null before dereferencing *any* pointer is a coding standard.  It allows the code to remain robust in other usage contexts or maintenance, where changes made elsewhere may cause the pointer to be null.

You could either remove the rule from the analysis profile, or suppress this specific instance with whatever message suppression comment format your tool uses.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing arrays out of bounds is a classic problem. In C this behavior is undefined so the variable `p_results_phase` might or not be NULL.

> 1. Will the pointer p_results_phase be assigned to NULL if the test_num variable is out of bounds?

Yes and NO. If you use an out of bound index you might point to a different memory address than intended. For eg:
`a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)` where `a` is the base address of the array and `i` is  the index into the array.
Now if you're accessing out of bound index such as `a[-100]`, that will just point to a memory address `(a + (-100)) == (a-100)` and if this address lies within your program's virtual address space then you'll just end up reading incorrect values, on the other hand writing to such a memory address will overwrite the contents present on that memory location which might result in other serious issues.
Also operating on out of bound indices might result in segmentation faults if the resulting memory address lies in the restricted area of the program's virtual address space.

> Will the pointer p_results_phase be assigned to NULL if the
> CAL_VER_PHASE is out of bounds?

Same answer. Out of bound array indices means you're reading/writing to an un-intended memory location. Performing read/write operations on these memory addresses will result in undefined outcomes.

Comment: `a[i]` evaluated as `*(a + i)` and not `(a + i)`.

Comment: Re “Now if you're accessing out of bound index such as `a[-100]`, that will just point to a memory address `(a + (-100)) == (a-100)`”: No, using an out of bounds index such as `a[-100]` is not specified to point to the memory address `a-100`. The behavior is not defined. That includes the fact it is not defined to reference `a-100`. While a simplistic “direct semantics” C implementation could point to `a-100`, common modern implementations are not simplistic. They include aggressive optimization that transforms programs in surprising ways, and a variety of other behaviors may result.

Comment: Re “No. Its undefined behavior.”: Since the behavior is not defined, the answer is yes, not no. Evaluating an expression with an out-of-bounds array index may result in assigning a null pointer to a variable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A 'Yes' to OP's question would mean all out of bound array accesses will be NULL access but since its undefined behavior we can't say for sure about it. I think because of the undefined behavior it needs to say both 'Yes' or 'No' to capture all possible outcomes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with the comment about modern compilers but I tried to explain this from a pointer arithmetic POV not taking into account any optimizations.

Comment: @akc5: Sorry, I missed an edit: The answer should be “Yes, it may happen.” Asserting either that it always happens or that it never happens is false.